# can't send data from flash builder 4.6 mobile flex to mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, flash, apache-flex

This is my flash builder 4.6 code.

```
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
        creationComplete="send_data()" title="HomeView"
        minWidth="955" minHeight="600">

    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->

        <s:HTTPService id="userRequest" url="/request_post2.php" 
                       useProxy="false" method="POST"> 
            <s:request xmlns=""> 
                <username>{username.text}</username> 
                <emailaddress>{emailaddress.text}</emailaddress> 
            </s:request>         
        </s:HTTPService> 

    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[       
            private function send_data():void { 
                userRequest.send(); 
            } 
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Form x="20" y="10" width="386"> 
        <s:FormItem> 
            <s:Label text="Username" />     
            <s:TextInput id="username"/> 
        </s:FormItem> 
        <s:FormItem> 
            <s:Label text="Email Address" />     
            <s:TextInput id="emailaddress"/> 
        </s:FormItem> 
        <s:Button label="Submit" click="send_data()"/> 
    </s:Form> 
</s:View>
```

and this is my php code i am using .

```
<?php 
define( "DATABASE_SERVER", "*********" ); 
define( "DATABASE_USERNAME", "**************" ); 
define( "DATABASE_PASSWORD", "*****************" ); 
define( "DATABASE_NAME", "*******************" ); 

//connect to the database. 
$mysql = mysql_connect(DATABASE_SERVER, DATABASE_USERNAME, DATABASE_PASSWORD); 

mysql_select_db( DATABASE_NAME ); 

// Quote variable to make safe  
function quote_smart($value) 
{ 
    // Stripslashes 
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) { 
    $value = stripslashes($value); 
    } 
    // Quote if not integer 
    if (!is_numeric($value)) { 
    $value = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($value) . "'"; 
    } 
    return $value; 
} 

if( $_POST["emailaddress"] AND $_POST["username"]) 
{ 
//add the user 
$Query = sprintf("INSERT INTO users VALUES ('', %s, %s)", 
        quote_smart($_POST['username']), quote_smart($_POST['emailaddress'])); 

$Result = mysql_query( $Query ); 
} 

//return a list of all the users 
$Query = "SELECT * from users"; 
$Result = mysql_query( $Query ); 

$Return = "<users>"; 

while ( $User = mysql_fetch_object( $Result ) ) 
{ 
$Return .= "<user><userid>".$User->userid."</userid><username>". 
            $User->username."</username><emailaddress>". 
            $User->emailaddress."</emailaddress></user>"; 
} 
$Return .= "</users>"; 
mysql_free_result( $Result ); 
print ($Return) 
?>
```

i found this code online and tried to make it work but had no success, and i don't see any error message i can search for .

i am debugging on virtual device.

this is the php code, the working one.

```
<?php 
 $v1= $_POST['username'];
 $v2= $_POST['emailaddress'];

 // include db connect class
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();
  mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8;");

mysql_query("SET CHARACTER_SET utf8;");

 // mysql inserting a new row
 $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(username,emailaddress) VALUES('$v1','$v2')");
echo $result;

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

you should put ResultEvent handler and a FaultEvent handler in your flex code.

```
 <s:HTTPService id="userRequest" url="/request_post2.php" result="myResultHandler(event)" fault="myFaultHandler(event)"
                   useProxy="false" method="POST"> 
        <s:request xmlns=""> 
            <username>{username.text}</username> 
            <emailaddress>{emailaddress.text}</emailaddress> 
        </s:request>         
    </s:HTTPService>
```

In your as3 script declare the methods referenced in the mxml:

```
private function myResultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void{
    Alert.show(event.result.toString());
}

private function myFaultHandler(event:FaultEvent):void{
    Alert.show(event.fault.toString());
}
```

I'not sure the "print" statement on php can be read correctly by Flex.
I would use a "echo" statement.
Hope to be helpful

Comment: thanks i did what u suggested and i still have nothing . perhaps it's a php code error. i'm looking into it, if there are other suggestion, they're most welcome

Comment: the problem was in my php code i changed it and it is working now, i can insert data into my database and thanks to u i get results of success or failure. now i will start working on loading data from the database to the app itself.